# Generate random numbers in each row between 1 and a particular value in a column

Tags: r, random, sample

I am stuck for quite a while now and really interested in how to achieve this. I have a data frame and I want to add another column with random numbers between 1 and the number that is in that row under the column `Amount`. How can I do this?
This is what I have now:

```
dataframe$newColumn <- sample(1:30, nrow(dataframe), replace = T)
```

but I don't want it to go from 1 to 30, but rather have the number in `Amount` column as the maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using base R you can use `vapply()` to iterate over `dataframe$Amount`, calling `sample()` for each value in `dataframe$Amount`

```
dataframe$newColumn <- vapply(dataframe$Amount, sample, integer(1), size = 1)
```

This is equivalent to calling

```
sample(dataframe$Amount[i], size = 1)
```

for each row `i` in `dataframe`. Note that if the first argument to `sample()` is a single value `n`, `sample(n)` expands this to `1:n`.

```r
sample(5)
## [1] 5 2 4 1 3
```

We use `integer(1)` in `vapply()` for the `FUN.VALUE` argument to, in essence, declare that the output of each of the above iterations will be an `integer`. You can achieve the same result with `map_int()` from the [purrr](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/) package:

```r
dataframe$newColumn <- purrr::map_int(dataframe$Amount, sample, size = 1)
```

Comment: maybe explain what `integer(1)` is doing (since `vapply()` is less widely used than it should be)?

Comment: @BenBolker sure! I agree, `vapply()` feels a little magical without talking about that argument. I also added a mention to `purrr::map_int()`.

Answer (score 4):

Tidyverse solution with `dplyr`:

```
foo <- data.frame(Amount = 1:10)
foo %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(newColumn = sample(Amount, 1))
```